# TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived. Django 1.8, python 2.7

Tags: django, python-2.7, metaclass

I am getting the following exception about the meta-class when using Python 2.7 and Django 1.8:

`TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived`

The exception does not always appear and I am finding it hard to track where the problem actually happened because it mysteriously disappeared later then.

The problem comes from the `resource.py` in django-framework, function `filter_response()`:

```
return self.serialize(obj)
```

Can anyone tell me why this error occurs?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. We need to see the full traceback at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few weeks and that problem happen again.
I found out because the application running in multi process and one of the bad process broke the _meta class.